# Qt 5.9 QML How to show ScrollBar on key up/down in material style with Flickable TextArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I want to put some text in a `Flickable` that can also scroll using keys up and down. It works, but the scrollbar does not show when scrolling with keys after it has already faded. Mouse wheel scrolling works fine.

`-style universal` doesn't show
`-style material` doesn't show
`-style default` *does* show

here's my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Flickable
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        focus: true

        TextArea.flickable: TextArea 
        {
            text:

        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, " +
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna " +
        "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation " +
        "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cosnsequat. " +

        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, " +
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna " +
        "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation " +
        "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cosnsequat. " +

        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, " +
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna " +
        "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation " +
        "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cosnsequat. " +

        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, " +
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna " +
        "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation " +
        "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cosnsequat. " ;


            font.pixelSize: 25
            wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
            readOnly: true
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { id: scrollBar }

        // up/down keys described here:
        // https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html
        Keys.onUpPressed: scrollBar.decrease()
        Keys.onDownPressed: scrollBar.increase()

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's an oversight that the ScrollBar does not flash as expected with the Material and Universal styles. A fix is on the way. Hopefully lands to Qt 5.9.1: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/196860/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend like this for mobile applications:

```
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
  id: scrollBar
  policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
  interactive: false
}
```

You can see: [policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#policy-prop) and [interactive](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#interactive-prop) props.

Comment: Thanks, but that shows the scrollbar all the time, rather than it fading.